# UV Unwrapping is eneven

Tags: modeling, uv-image-editor

I am trying to unwrap a object (shirt) in the blender by marking seams. I added new **uv grid** image using image texture node.  But for some reason the pattern on unwrapped image is not even on both side. I don't have much experience when it comes to uv unwrpping so I'm not able to figure out what the problem is .I am attaching .blend file, hope that helps.

Thanks in advance.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hUIulFz6sgqSMBpHU_EF_8sDqgf0X2nY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello :). Please add an image of you mesh and of your UV map. You'll have a better chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the shirt, there is a Ngon that breaks the flow of the edge loops, so your vertical Seam fails to "cut" the model in two halves :
[image]

A quick fix would be to add a Seam along on side of this Ngon :
[image]

It would also be a good idea to add a Seam inside the arm, same position as outside :
[image]

For your future models, i would suggest avoiding unnecessary NGons. Also, you can use the Solidify modifier instead of modelling the outside and the inside, it's much easier and avoid this kind of traps.

Comment: oops you're right, didn't even realized there was a seam inside  ;)

Comment: @thibsert thanks for your help. Adding seam across the ngon did the trick. Also I had used solidify modifier but before going for unwrapping, I applied all the modifiers. Thanks for your suggestions :p.